# Trying to run third party .NET application in mono on an ARM in linux - Cassini source code compatibility?

Tags: c#, .net, cassini

I am trying to run a third party .NET application in mono on an ARM in Linux, but am getting the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Cassini, Version=3.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76c670a36a765fa4' or one of its dependencies.

I was considering compiling the Cassini source code available from Microsoft on the ARM, but the `PublicKeyToken` property in the error makes me think the assembly would have to be signed by Microsoft to work with this third party application. Am I correct?

Comment: Cassini is the .net web development server. When you select run you attach to an instance of the .net web server and can debug and step through. However, I don't know why you would be missing this:(

Comment: On windows, it is registered in the GAC, so I would search for the .dll on your machine first.  If you find it, copy it to the executing directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct:  [CLR Inside Out: Using Strong Name Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx)